# Short request texts on server-status

Tags: apache-2.4

I've recently noticed that requests in the /server-status page are incomplete, that is they're cut at index 64. See below:

```
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0
POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0
GET /wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/settings.cs
GET /wp-content/plugins/indeed-my-logos-vc/files/css/font-aweso
POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1547724681.90076208114624023437
GET /wp-content/uploads/2019/01/urun-lvl05-pegasus-koltuk-takim
GET /index.php?route=product/product&path=62&product_id=347 HTT
```

[image: screenshot of server-status page]

Is there a way to modify this page (get the full path)? If so, how?

Comment: Does the machine readable version `server-status?auto` show the complete URL and is your observation just a rendering choice to keep theHTML  table nice and aligned? - altenatively see if setting [`ExtendedStatus`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#extendedstatus) to `On` makes a difference

Comment: @HBruijn `server-status?auto` doesn't return processes; only server, cpu, and ssl information. I want to see the full paths in `server-status`. Normally, I'd go with `server-status?auto`, but it lacks processes. Even if it didn't, now I'm not sure if the paths will be full. They might be cut like in the page `server-status`. Also I've tested `ExtendedStatus On` (it was in `apache/conf/extra/httpd-info.conf`) on localhost (XAMPP), but didn't work.  I'll try it on remote soon. Tbh, I'm not sure what `ExtendedStatus On` will provide. I've searched an example output, but couldn't find anything.